# Operators on Scala short return Int?

Tags: scala, short

I am new to Scala and I am curious why do `+` or `+=` operators return a `Int` instead of a `Short`? I had a simple 
code as follows,

```
count :Short
count += 1.toShort
```

but the `+=` operator returns an `Int`, I am assuming this is deliberate and want to know the reason.

I need this to be short because I am storing the result in a DB and would like to save space on the disk. I could of course let the calculations happen in `Int` and then always call `.toShort` on the result before storing but this is a bit counter intuitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost certainly because that's how it's handled in Java and JVM Bytecode. Having widening promotion to `integer` is consistent with how it's handled in Java, and removes the need to do any additional casting operations. From the [Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to
>   double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is
>   converted to float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the
>   other is converted to long.
> - **Otherwise, both operands are converted to
>   type int.**

emphasis mine. The reason Java (the language) does it this way is because of how the JVM specification is written. From the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.1),

> Note that most instructions in Table 2.2 **do not have forms for the integral types byte, char, and short.** None have forms for the boolean type. A compiler encodes loads of literal values of types byte and short using Java Virtual Machine instructions that **sign-extend those values to values of type int** at compile-time or run-time. Loads of literal values of types boolean and char are encoded using instructions that zero-extend the literal to a value of type int at compile-time or run-time. Likewise, loads from arrays of values of type boolean, byte, short, and char are encoded using Java Virtual Machine instructions that sign-extend or zero-extend the values to values of type int. Thus, **most operations on values of actual types boolean, byte, char, and short are correctly performed by instructions operating on values of computational type int**.

Emphasis again mine. So Scala does this because its the easiest, most efficient way to work with the options given by the JVM.

Comment: Second quote is JVMS, not JLS. SLS http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/12-the-scala-standard-library.html#numeric-value-types and sample old discussion about widening conversions https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-internals/Gi-54GeWv-M/8nBSrrCIeQ4J

Answer (score 0):

Atul, Good question. Here are my thoughts - 
When I looked at [ScalaDoc for "Short"](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/#scala.Short), the operator `+=` was not there. I am guessing this means the compiler helps you a bit and translates it to `count = 1.toShort + count`. Now the `+` operator always returns an `Int`.
Does that make sense?

The question changed after I answered it. My answer now only addresses the first part.

Hope that still helps.

Comment: Yes I figured that out - but I could not reconcile with the fact that, when I am adding two shorts I get an Int back. But the answer below makes sense if it is a Java Language restriction.

Comment: Glad you got your answer!